# How do obtain wrapped btc and wrapped ada in a local test network or a live test network like ropsten?

Tags: ropsten, testnets, testrpc, testing, exchanges

In the local test network and ropsten test network, it's easy to obtain ethereum but I need other tokens in order to do testing. I'm not sure how to obtain those tokens for testing.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to have this done by others for you. You can deploy any ERC-20 token yourself on the testnet and cal it WBTC.

Comment: Thanks for your answer which I will try to use.

While this is true, it'd be nice if there's a standardized way for everyone on ropsten to obtain tokens from the same address. Otherwise everyone will do repeated work of finding the actual token address on eth main net, copy the code, and deploy it.